# Adjust height of JFoenix Label Float

Tags: css, javafx, label, jfoenix

I have a JavaFX application using JFoenix for UI elements and they have a label float feature. I have added background shading to the text field however the labels need to be slightly higher elevated to clear the shaded box, especially so on the jfxcombobox element. Is it possible to lift just this label without effecting prompt text or user entered text?

[image: Example]
[image: Example 2]

I attempted to add a CSS class to the promptText element in JFXTextAreaSkinAndroid however it also moved the base prompt text.